# How to display the RTSP video on Next.js project?

Tags: next.js, rtsp

I am going to display the rtsp video on Next.js project by using rtsp video url.
Please let me know how to do this from scratch.
Here is my rtsp video url link.
rtsp://enayat:enayat@110.39.14.182:14119/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0

I tried to figure out this problem by using `react-player` module.
But it doesn't work well.

Please help me.
Thanks.